# Where can I find "Try This" solutions on Stroustrup's book Programming Principles & Practices?

Tags: c++

I just need to double check my soulutions, but I can't find any solutions posted in the web.

Would be glad if you help me because I've set myself a goal to learn c++ during holidays.

In particular I need help with a function exercise, this is what I have so far:

```
//(not using multiplication)
int square(int a)
{
    int result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < a)
    {
        result += result;
        ++count;
        return result;
    }
}

int main()
{
        int x = 0;
        x = square(5);
        cout << x;
}
```

But my output is 0.

Comment: `result` starts at `0`, and `0 += 0 === 0`.  perhaps you needed to do something with `a`?

Comment: Yes you're right, my brain is on holiday mode right now

Comment: Only for code readability I will suggest to use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is `0`, so adding it to itself, no matter how many times, will result in `0`. If you're attempting to square `a`, you should add that to the `result`. Additionally, the `return` statement should be outside the loop, not inside it:

```cpp
int square(int a)
{
    int result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < a)
    {
        result += a; // Here!
        ++count;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb now xD, thanks. Can you help with finding solutions though? I can't ask here for every problem that I face. Oh and also, is there a way to print only the final result, like a*a, and not all the calculations?

Comment: @NickNameNick you can output the result of the function call - e.g., `cout << square(7) << endl;`.